# How to prepend to a string that comes out of a pipe

Tags: bash

I have two strings saved in a bash variable delimited by `:`. I want to get extract the second string, prepend that with `THIS_VAR=` and append it to a file named `saved.txt`

For example if myVar="abc:pqr", `THIS_VAR=pqr` should be appended to saved.txt.

This is what I have so far,

```
myVar="abc:pqr"
echo $myVar | cut -d ':' -f 2  >> saved.txt
```

How do I prepend `THIS_VAR=`?

Comment: What about using just `echo THIS_VAR=${myVar/*:} >> saved.txt`? And if you want the first field instead, just use `echo THIS_VAR=${myVar/:*}` (notice the position of the `:`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf 'THIS_VAR=%q\n' "${myVar#*:}"
```

See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and run `help printf`.

Answer (score 2):

The more general solution in addition to @konsolebox's answer is piping into a compound statement, where you can perform arbitrary operations:

```
echo This is in the middle | {
    echo This is first
    cat
    echo This is last
}
```